# How can I calculate the difference between two timestamps using micropython?

Tags: micropython, real-time-clock, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a raspberry pi pico and a DS3231 real time clock hooked up to it. I'm able to receive the current time in BCD  and format it in a string by Hours:Minutes:seconds "00:00:00" using the DS3231 sample code that has been provided from the waveshare wiki [waveshare wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-RTC-DS3231)

I've tried using a datetime module but I get the error "no module named datetime" so I'm unsure if it's included within micropython.

this was my attempt

```
def elapsed_time(self, start, end):
    start_time = datetime.strptime(start,"%H:%M:%S")
    end_time = datetime.strptime(end,"%H:%M:%S")
    
    return end_time - start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find [datetime](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/python-stdlib/datetime) in the [micropython-lib](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib) repository, a collection of curated (by the MicroPython core team) libraries useful when developing MicroPython applications.

For now, the easiest way to use datetime is to copy `datetime.py` to your device and ensure it can be found in your `sys.path`.

Comment: I checked out that datetime library, but it doesn't include strptime which I was hoping it had.